# What are these numbers in this android java files?

Tags: java, android

So I've been trying to make some app and was looking for some inspiration. I was browsing one app on github and was looking at the code. There was numbers along with the attributes. I don't understand what are those numbers. Can anyone help explain what are these numbers in those android files?

```
public static final class attr {
    public static final int actionBarDivider = 2130772069;
    public static final int actionBarItemBackground = 2130772070;
    public static final int actionBarPopupTheme = 2130772063;
    public static final int actionBarSize = 2130772068;
    public static final int actionBarSplitStyle = 2130772065;
    public static final int actionBarStyle = 2130772064;
    public static final int actionBarTabBarStyle = 2130772059;
    public static final int actionBarTabStyle = 2130772058;
    public static final int actionBarTabTextStyle = 2130772060;
    public static final int actionBarTheme = 2130772066;
    public static final int actionBarWidgetTheme = 2130772067;
    public static final int actionButtonStyle = 2130772093;
    public static final int actionDropDownStyle = 2130772088;
    public static final int actionLayout = 2130772023;
    public static final int actionMenuTextAppearance = 2130772071;
    public static final int actionMenuTextColor = 2130772072;
    public static final int actionModeBackground = 2130772075;
    public static final int actionModeCloseButtonStyle = 2130772074;
    public static final int actionModeCloseDrawable = 2130772077;
    public static final int actionModeCopyDrawable = 2130772079;
    public static final int actionModeCutDrawable = 2130772078;
    public static final int actionModeFindDrawable = 2130772083;
```

what are those numbers after the equal signs?

and they have been used in another android java files of the same app like this..

```
this.et = (EditText) findViewById(PT1293.id.etRoll);
this.Scloth.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, 17367049, this.branch));
```

Comment: What GitHub repo are you looking at?

Comment: I didn't exactly save the link. I was just browsing randomly and came around a repo, saw this code and saved few lines on a notepad and thought I would crack it later that what those numbers are but I couldn't so I'm asking here.

Comment: From the looks of the code, it seems more like you are reverse-engineering an APK. Programmers don't write Android apps the way your code depicts, but decompilers do.

Comment: They are probably codes for somethng. Seems they picked some numbers that would be unlikely to use as numbers.

Comment: Those are constants, unfortunately their names are not following the java coding conventions (the class name neither does). These values are fixed and their intention is to be used all over the code (since they are public not only in this class) to set certain attributes which customize the appearance of the app.

Comment: @CommonsWare So what exactly those numbers would mean? Do they have any purpose?

Comment: Those numbers look like Resource Id, to identify a Resource such as a Color, a String or a Drawable

Comment: They are identifiers of [resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals#Resources) that are part of the app, whether created by the app developer or contributed via libraries.

Comment: @CommonsWare is Right, an Android Developer would likely more use R.string.example than a such hardcoded id

Answer (score 4):

Those numbers are generated in The Project's R Class

> Once you externalize your app resources, you can access them using resource IDs that are generated in your project's R class. This document shows you how to group your resources in your Android project and provide alternative resources for specific device configurations, and then access them from your app code or other XML files.

For example, if string1 has id 4445 then R.string.string1 is 4445

But usually (always) to access a resource, we do **not** hardcode the Resource identifier as int like this. Instead, they are generated, we access the Resource using R.string.string1 for example.

As @CommonsWare stated, it look like reverse engineering of an Apk,

For more infos see [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources).